# django の管理サイトを本番環境でも有効化したい

Tags: django

現在 heroku 上で django を利用したWebアプリケーションを動かしています。
本番環境では settings.py 内の DEBUG 変数を False としているのですが、そのせいで管理サイトへアクセスすると400エラーとなってしまいます。
(DEBUG=Trueとすればアクセスできます)

デバッグモードで運用するわけにもいきませんし、管理サイトも有効化しておきたいのですが、なにか回避方法はありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heroku上では、管理サイト以外のページは表示されていますか。
もし管理サイト以外のページも表示できていないようならば、`ALLOWED_HOSTS`の設定に問題がある可能性があります。

settings.py

```
# herokuのURLを追加
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['hoge.heroku.com']
```

また、エラーメッセージがありましたら、そちらも併せて教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます！

ALLOWED_HOSTS には本番のドメインを指定しておりまして、管理サイト以外にはアクセスができています。

エラーメッセージは特になく、デフォルトのエラー画面が返っているように思います。
<h1>Bad Request (400)</h1>

レスポンスヘッダを見ても、原因を思われるようなものは何もありませんでした。

Comment: 管理サイト以外のページで画像やcssファイルなど(staticファイル)は読み込めていますか。
また、管理サイト以外のページではデータベースのデータは利用していますか(利用している場合は正しく出力されていますか)。
Djangoのバージョン、バックエンドのデータベース、`heroku logs`のログメッセージ等についても教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS に指定していた本番のドメイン名にタイポが見つかり、それを修正したところ無事アクセスできるようになりました。。
大変失礼いたしました。。